# return zero result when I get the json result but I get the result when I directly access the link

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have write little php code to get the address info with the code below:

```
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Test Technology PTY Ltd., Rosslyn Street, Bellevue Hill, New South Wales, Australia&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);
print $output;
for($j=0;$j<count($output->results[0]->address_components);$j++){
echo '<b>'.$output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->types[0].': </b>  '.$output->results[0]->address_components[$j]->long_name.'<br/>';
}
```

When I print the $output, It shows zero result. But when I access the link directly:http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Test Technology PTY Ltd., Rosslyn Street, Bellevue Hill, New South Wales, Australia&sensor=false in the browser.The address info was listed. So I would like to ask how to correct my code to get it work?

Thank you very much~

Tim

Answer (score 0):

If you create a variable called address and wrap in urlencode it will work for you (see below).

```
$address = urlencode("Test Technology PTY Ltd., Rosslyn Street, Bellevue Hill, New South Wales, Australia");

$geocode = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}");
```